# PHP Adwords monthly searches

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I am looking for a way to get monthly searches volume for a keyword with google adwords api. The way I've found requires using developer token which I haven't.
Thanks.

Comment: Which way have you tried?

Comment: @LordWilmore A way I've found on other question here.

Comment: You should explain what you have tried to that others can offer alternative solutions.  If you don't tell us what you've tried then how can anybody possibly tell you what to try as an alternative?

Comment: @LordWilmore I tried to use the TargetingServiceIdea library but it requires developer token which google adwords didn't approved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just get a developer token. Follow the instructions in the link below.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/signup

Comment: I create one three days before but they didn't send me any message about approval or rejection.